# SQL пересечение date

Tags: mysql, sql

имеется в таблицe result записи
Например:

```
id   start_date   end_date
1    2017-01-01   2017-06-30
2    2017-07-01   2017-12-31
```

Как определить пересекающиеся записи (тут они не пересекаются)

Количество записей может быть хоть сколько.
Использую MySQL

Comment: join таблицы самой с собой и условие на пересечение дат и неравенство id в where

Comment: @Mike, ну например: SELECt * FROM result INNER JOIN result on result WHERE, а что В WHERE писать?

Comment: только алиасы назначьте `from result A join result B on A.start_date <= B.end_date and A.end_date >= B.start_date and A.id!=B.id`

Comment: Если нужны только пересечения (не касания) - равенства сделать строгими и убрать проверку неравенства id.

Comment: *Количество записей может быть хоть сколько.* Допустим, 4 записи пересекаются (1-5, 2-4, 4-7, 6-8). Какой результат Вы при этом хотите увидеть? *Использую MySQL* Версию кто будет указывать? или предлагается угадать?